# How do I make the 3D manipulator straight instead of sitting at an angle?

Tags: 3d-manipulator

How can I make the 3d manipulator straight again after being angled like this:

[image: 3d cursor]

I am now only able to drag verticles diagonally but what I want is to drag them straight along the x, y or z axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your transform manipulator orientation is not set to Global:

[image]

Comment: Surely you want to make sure it *is* set to *Global*?

Comment: If he wants to move vertices along world X axis, yes. As it appears in the image I think the transform orientation is set to Local and the Object is rotated along the Y axis.